# Php variable need to get in jquery popup

Tags: php, jquery

this is my html table part.. popup will open when i click on my update button.

```
<?php
{
    include("config/dbconfig.php");
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_company");
    echo"<table>";
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
        $s=  $row['company_id'];

        $r= $row['company_name'];

        $a= $row['head_office_city'];

        echo"<tr><td>".$r."</td><td>".$a."</td>

        <td><a href=\"#\" class=\"topopup\" id=\"update_comp\" \"><img title='update details' alt=\"Delete\" class='del' src='images/update.png'/></a> </td>

        <td><a href=\"delete_company.php?column1=".$row['company_id']."\"><img title='make company inactive' alt=\"Delete\" class='del' src='images/delete.png'/></a> </td></tr>";

    }
    echo"</table>";
}
?>

<div id="toPopup">

    <div class="close"></div>
    <span class="ecs_tooltip">Press Esc to close <span class="arrow"></span></span>
    <div id="popup_content"> <!--your content start-->
```

this is the kind of popup that i'm using

in this popup rest part of editing company details should be done. for that I need to get `company_id`.

How I get this `$company_id` value to popup page?

Comment: Please do something about the whitespace in your source code to make it less horrible.

Comment: Need more information like what kind of popup window code you are using!! Please try to provide more information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write it like you PHP code like this

```
<td>
    <a href=\"#\" class=\"topopup\" id=\"update_comp\" onclick=\"return openPoup('".$row['company_id']."')\" \">
        <img title='update details' alt=\"Delete\" class='del' src='images/update.png'/>
    </a> 
</td>
```

and in JavaScript you can write

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openPoup(companyId){
        window.open('/editcomapny.php?comapnyId='+companyId);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: hi thnx for the rapid replay.. now i'm getting company_id to one other  window but actually i need to display  all the company details to enable editing. that would come in a jquery popup . i hope you can understand the problem..

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><a href=\"#\" class=\"topopup\" id=\"update_comp\" onClick=\"return callYourPopup(".$row['company_id'].");\">


<script type="text/javascript">
function callYourPopup(id) {
    alert("Do something with " + id);
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: how to get this value to the popup division?

Comment: If your popup plugin supports overgiving params in form of a literal you can do something like this:
$.openYourModal({
params: { id: id}
});

otherwise you send the new params via get / request http "modalurl.php?id="+id

Comment: thnx @nando its working now. i just send param via get as you mention.